# Access sessions in Template using Django 1.1.4

Tags: python, django, session

I have created a session in my view. I have called it in my template. But it throws an error stating invalid syntax. I have checked my settings.py and under MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES the session is enabled. When ever I run my page it throws the error. Please see below

Views.py

```
request.session["name"] = "name"
return render_to_response('index.html',context_instance = RequestContext(request,{'session':'name'})
```

index.html

```
{{ request.session.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you posted your code correctly you are missing closing parentheses for `render_to_response`

`return render_to_response('index.html',context_instance = RequestContext(request,{'session':'name'}))`

Comment: I cannot view the value of the session. I have added in more items in the render_to_response